# different unexpected errors when building with -pg option

Tags: c++, sockets, gdb, g++, profiling

My home task was to write a tool that will transfer large data via sockets.
The main idea behind my code is not too sophisticated, so i'll just give following pseudo code :

```
alignas( 4 ) struct package :
  uint8_t type , is_eof , padding[ 2 ] ;
  uint32_t size , checksum ; 
  uint8_t data[ large_size ] ;

function send :
   read amount of data to the "package" ( with std::istream::read ) ; 
   form a "package" : load gcount() of read bytes, checksum, etc. 
                      ( hton* are used on this step ) ;
   send "package" ( sendall from beej's guide ) ;
   wait for approve package ;

function receive :
   receive a "package" ( recv with MSG_WAITALL ) ;
   unpack : calc checksum and check ( crc ), etc ;
   write data to ostream ( std::ostream::write ) ;
   send approve package ;
```

On regular build ( g++-5 ) everything works perfectly as expected - sender sends data, receiver 
 receives, checks, and sends a response. Moreover, due to my naive benchmarks 
 on LAN, it works only 1.5x slower then transferring via ftp.)

But when i add '-pg' flag to g++'s options, after few packages receiver 
 starts to receive packages with garbage.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on.?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're getting your sockets so this is a wild guess based on a similar problem I saw in 2003 or so:

You have some code that is "helpfully" closing Unix file descriptors from 3 to 1024 (or 4096, or NOFILE, etc). And then reusing FD 3 for a socket.

HINT: PROFILING USES A FILE DESCRIPTOR.

In my similar problem in the past, the socket opened on FD 3 was being sent all of the profiling data interleaved with the expected data.

IF YOU DIDN'T OPEN IT, DON'T CLOSE IT.

Comment: well, i get sockets' descriptors via POSIX 'socket', and the only place where the code calls 'close' is wrapper's destructor. 
"You have some code that is "helpfully" closing Unix file descriptors from 3 to 1024" where can i find it.? (i have an idea already, ill check).

Comment: As I said it was a guess. Grep your code for "close". Such close loops are often found in backgrounder, daemonize, double fork() code near service startup.